# Bind multiple parameters into mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

Right now I need to use the following structure to cope with binding multiple parameters into a mysqli query:

```
if ($words_total == 1)
{
    $statement -> bind_param("s", $words[0]);
}
else if ($words_total == 2)
{
    $statement -> bind_param("ss", $words[0], $words[1]);
}
else if ($words_total == 3)
{
    $statement -> bind_param("sss", $words[0], $words[1], $words[2]);
}

//and so on....
```

I work out the number of question marks using the code below and insert it into my query:

```
$marks = "";
for($i = 1; $i<=$words_total; $i++) {
    if ($i == $words_total)
    {
        $marks .= "?";
    }
    else
    {
        $marks .= "?,";
    }
}
```

My question is surely there must be a way of handling as many inputs into the query as I need dynamically. Hardcoding the `bind_param()` seems like a really bad way of handling this.

I am using php version 5.4.10

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately, by default, bind_param() doesn't accept an array instead of separate variables. However, since PHP 5.6 there is a magnificent improvement that will do the trick.

To bind an arbitrary number of variables into mysqli query you will need an [argument unpacking operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-151). It will make the operation as simple and smooth as possible.

For example, to use a PHP array with a mysql's `IN()` operator, you will need the following code

```
// our array
$array = ['a','b','c']; 

// create an SQL query with placeholders and prepare it
$in    = str_repeat('?,', count($array) - 1) . '?'; //  returns ?,?,?...
$sql   = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE city IN ($in)"; 
$stmt  = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

// create the types string dynamically and bind an array
$types = str_repeat('s', count($array)); // returns sss...
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$array); 

// execute and fetch the rows
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // fetch the data
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this - I was literally in despair over my ugly solution to this problem. I agree that error reporting is a weakness of mine that I need to spend the time to learn more about. I only learned php like 2 months ago so up till now it's all been about being able to do as much as possible. Now I think I have to maybe focus more on doing things as well as possible!! Hugs and thanks!