# How use multiple parameters on mysqli_stmt_bind_param?

Tags: php, mysqli, bind, param

Hi guys im trying write method to Select data from mysql using function prepare. My code is like this:

```
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($this -> conn, $query)) {
                    //$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1=?";
                    //$types = "s";
                    //$param = "funny";

            /* bind parameters for markers */
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, $param);

            /* execute query */
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            /* bind result variables */
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            $i = 0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $c[$i] = $row;
                $i++;
            }

            /* close statement */
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            return $c;
        }
```

Using this functions i can get data only with single parameter:

```
/* bind parameters for markers */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, $param);
```

Now i need put not only single parameter also multiple parameters. And tried this code:

```
/* bind parameters for markers */
$msbp = array($stmt, $types, $param);
call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', $msbp);
```

But its not work. Any ideas to this method?

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: Parameter 3 to mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expected to be a reference!

Comment: But your query has only one `?`

Comment: My second query is like this. SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1=? AND col2=?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870999/bind-multiple-parameters-into-mysqli-query

Answer (score -2):

I found a very interesting function here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#107200 
Respect to Darren! Really good function.