# Proper way to dynamically bind parameters in MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm writing an `OOP` database class for `mysqli`. I want all queries to be prepared, but I'm having difficulties binding parameters to queries dynamically.
I want the query method API to look like this

```
query($sql, $param)
```

However, I don't know how to bind the parameters dynamically within the method. I searched for examples in `PHP` manual and saw codes like these:

```
$method = new ReflectionMethod('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_param'); 
$method->invokeArgs($stmt, $params);    
$stmt->execute();
```

I know the `ReflectionMethod()`  will execute the method for the object or class, but I don't understand how it works in this case, considering that each parameter has a `type` which should be specified while `binding`.

How can I bind the parameters dynamically?

Secondly, how does `ReflectionMethod()` work in this situation?

Comment: Why not just use PDO? http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. It does what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Here goes a [a pretty canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874410/285587)

Answer (score 0):

I have always use this custom function I wrote to work on mysqli and it works for me.

```
public function execute_prepared_query_reflection ($array_list)
    {
        $ret_stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->conn, $this->sql);    
        //call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge (array($this->statement, $param_listtypes), $param_list));
        //$this->statement->bind_param("issdssssss", $param_staffid, $param_duration, $param_dateappraised, $param_totalmark, $param_detailBySuperv, $param_sumByHead, $param_recommendation, $param_enteredby);
        if ($ret_stmt!=false)
        {
            $method    = new ReflectionMethod('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_param');
            $method->invokeArgs($ret_stmt, $this->createArrayRef($array_list));               
            $retvar = $ret_stmt->execute();  
        } 
        $method = null;
        $ret_stmt = null;

    }
```