# Determining variable type and size in an insert function for a db class PHP

Tags: php, database, class, oop, mysqli

I have a database class as follows:

```
class Db
{
public $mysqli = null;

public function __construct($port = NULL)
{
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/'.'config.php';
    if($port == NULL)
        $port = ini_get('mysqli.default_port');

    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB, $port)
        or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');

    if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Error MySQLi: ( " . $this->mysqli->connect_errno  . ") " . $this->mysqli->connect_error;
        exit();
     }
       $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); 
}
```

All of which works fine, I've added this function:

```
public function insert($sql, $bind) {
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $bind[0], $bind[1], $bind[2], $bind[3], $bind[4], $bind[5], $bind[6]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

The problem of course, is that this isn't very dynamic. I may only have 2 things to bind, and they won't necessarily be strings.

So for example I do this:

```
$db = new Db();
$strings = array ($chosenImage, $id);
$db->insert("INSERT INTO Media VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)", $strings);
```

So this is only two binds.

My question then is two fold:
1) How do I best turn this function into one that assesses the array for type, and size in as clean a fashion as possible?

2) Further, with a similar function (lets call it recall) How would I use a select statement to return 2 items, and bind them for the return (assuming the amount that I want to return may change depending on the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-1. Having distinct function for insert is quite wrong idea. One actually need only helper for SET statement, to create it dynamically. The rest have to be called using conventional `query()` function.
0. Types aren't that important, using `s` for everything is quite all right.

1. [call_user_func_array()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17874410/285587)
2. [get_result()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will look into points 1 and 2 :)
I do have a question about point -1 if I may. Could you elaborate on it? I don't quite understand. What if in one point I want to insert something but don't want to return it. Then another time I want to recall some data from the database, do I not need two separate things for that?
Also I did not know about point 0, I appreciate you telling me this as I thought it was very strict

Comment: Real SQL syntax is not that poor as you picture it. There is REPLACE query, INSERT IGNORE and dozen other forms of mere INSERT.  Instead of trying to rewrite [extremely limited] subset of SQL in PHP, create an API which will let you run *any* SQL query, all following the same quality and safety rules. If you don't want data fetched - that's easy: just don't use a function that fetches something.

Comment: 1. is not that easy though. I've added link to example