# Bind array to mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Array which stores the paths/names of images:
`$wall_filenames[]`

Contents of `$wall_filenames:`

`Array ( [0] => wallpapers/2014/03/calendar-thumbnail-520x264.jpg 
         [1] => wallpapers/2014/03/calendar-preview2-786x305.jpg )`

MySQL Query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO walls(wall_name, wall_thumbnail_path, wall_preview1_path, 
        wall_preview2_path, wall_preview3_path,
        upload_date, d_1280x800_path, d_1366x768_path, d_1920x1080_path,
        p_640x960_path, p_640x1136_path, p_720x1280_path, p_768x1280_path,
        p_1080x1920_path, t_1024x768_path, t_2048x1536_path)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$insert_wall = $connectDB->prepare($sql);
```

So the problem is, the table contains several columns. But when I insert once, it not necessary to upload all files which in my example above I'm only uploading two. What I need to do is add those array elements to there appropriate columns in my table. In this case I want `$wall_filenames[0]` to be stored to `wall_thumbnail_path` and `$wall_filenames[1]` to `wall_preview2_path`. I'm not sure how can I bind an array using `bind_param()` to point to correct column in table.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874410/285587

Comment: @YourCommonSense This doesn't seem to be similar. That question is about a variable number of columns that need to be bound.

Comment: @vephelp also PLEASE note the code formatting and ALWAYS make it the same. Instead of moving half of the code off screen

Answer (score 0):

Include the array index when you call `bind_param`:

```
$insert_wall->bind_param('sss...', $wall_name, $wall_filenames[0], $wall_filenames[1], ...);
```

Comment: my `$wall_filenames[1]` contains the path for `preview2`, in this case it would store the path to a different column I guess.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice all the columns with similar names. But the idea is the same -- just put it in the appropriate place in the argument list.

Answer (score -2):

Be creative.

## Do not store the data that can be calculated.

There is **absolutely no sense** in storing **constant numbers** in database. Just develop some naming policy, then get rid of all these path columns, and check your files from the disk according to naming policy.

Comment: amm I think I'm not storing numbers in database, just using them as reference. but yes, thanks for your suggestion on using names instead of numbers.

Comment: There exists a place where suggestions can be offered, comments.

Comment: @vephelp you don't understand. **786x305** IS a number stored in database. Whlie there is no point in storing it there. Now get it?