# search engine - prepared statement with multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$keyword = explode(' ',$_GET['q']);//a b c d e
foreach($keyword => value){
  params[]=$value;
}
$query ="SELECT id,english FROM product WHERE CONCAT(english,Denglish) LIKE CONCAT ('%', ?, '%') ";
$search=$mysqli->prepare($query);
$search->bind_param('s',params);
$search->execute();
$search->bind_result($id,$english);
while($row = $search->fetch()) {
    echo $english;
}
```

=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================

Comment: This code is a terrible mess of PDO and mysqli intermixed. First of all make your mind and choose only one driver to deal with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870999/bind-multiple-parameters-into-mysqli-query/17874410#17874410