# Error with call_user_func_array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, array-merge, bindparam

I am having trouble with calling bind_param via call_user_func_array. I am trying to do it like this:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array($types), $params));
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in...
```

I thought it was because my array was malformed as other questions have noted but I did a var dump like this:

```
var_dump(array_merge(array($types), $params));
```

and I got this result, which I thought was the correct input format:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 's' (length=1)
  1 => string 'Hello' (length=5)
```

Please could somebody tell me where the error lies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind multiple parameters into mysqli query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870999/bind-multiple-parameters-into-mysqli-query)

Comment: Btw it is not `pdo` you're using, it's `mysqli`

Comment: @u_mulder please read my question before voting as a duplicate, I saw this specific question when trying to find a solution myself and it did not solve the problem as they mentioned that the input array was wrong whereas mine is correct as I demonstrated with a var_dump

Comment: The solution for your question is line `$bind[$key] = &$values[$key];` So, your `$params` array must store not values but references. That's all.